# OpenCL crashing while dynamic linking?

Tags: c++, qt, opencl

I am trying to load OpenCL library at run time so that the same exe can run on platforms which do not have OpenCL drivers without finding unresolved symbols. I am using Qt to do this but I dont think I am facing my problem due to Qt. Here is my function which checks if OpenCL 1.1 is installed or not:

```
QLibrary *MyOpenCL::openCLLibrary = NULL;

bool MyOpenCL::loadOpenCL()
{
    if(openCLLibrary)
        return  true;

    QLibrary *lib = new QLibrary("OpenCL");
    if(!lib->load())
        return false;

    bool result = false;
    typedef cl_int (*MyPlatorms)(cl_uint, cl_platform_id *, cl_uint *);
    MyPlatorms pobj = (MyPlatorms) lib->resolve("clGetPlatformIDs");
    if(pobj)
    {
        cl_uint nplatforms = 0;
        cl_uint myerr = pobj(0, NULL, &nplatforms);
        if((myerr == CL_SUCCESS) && (nplatforms > 0))
        {
            cl_platform_id *mplatforms = new cl_platform_id[nplatforms];
            myerr = pobj(nplatforms, mplatforms, NULL);

            typedef cl_int (*MyPlatformInfo)(cl_platform_id, cl_platform_info, size_t, void *, size_t *);
            MyPlatformInfo pinfoobj = (MyPlatformInfo) lib->resolve("clGetPlatformInfo");
            if(pinfoobj)
            {
                size_t size;
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nplatforms; i++)
                {
                    size = 0;
                    myerr = pinfoobj(mplatforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, 0, NULL, &size);//size = 27
                    if(size < 1)
                        continue;

                    char *ver = new char[size];
                    myerr = pinfoobj(mplatforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, size, ver, NULL);
                    qDebug() << endl << ver;//segmentation fault at this line
...
}
```

As can be seen Qt successfully resolved clGetPlatformIDs(). It even showed that there is 1 platform available. But when I pass the array to store the cl_platform_id, it crashes.
Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**
I am using Qt 4.8.1 with MinGW compiler using OpenCL APP SDK 2.9.
I am using the OpenCL 1.1 header from Khronos website.
My laptop which has Windows7 64 bit also has ATI Radeon 7670m GPU which has OpenCL 1.1 drivers.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're programming in C++, why are you using `calloc`? Why not `cl_platform_id *mplatforms = new cl_platform_id[nplatforms];`?

Comment: `QLibrary *MyOpenCL::openCLLibrary = NULL;` -> This is a very very bad idea. Please use `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QLibrary, myOpenCLLibrary)` instead in the source file (note, not the header). Not to mention, you should use Q_NULLPTR rather than "NULL".

Comment: @LaszloPapp Why? It looks like a normal `static` member variable definition.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg OpenCL is like a subset of the C language. All the tutorials I have seen so far use C style programming while using OpenCL. Well there be any problems in future if I use C style programming in C++?

Comment: @Cool_Coder Then thing with C++ using C functions is that there's really no difference when it comes to things like pointers. A pointer is a pointer is a pointer. *How* it was allocated doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: actually, there is some difference between C and C++ pointers, `void*` which is what Qt 4 was doing instead of QFunctionPointer for resolving the symbols. CoolCoder, can you paste the backtrace? Btw, why don'tyou specify the library version? You think all of them are compatible and supported in your application?

Comment: Also, you do not indicate which Qt version you are using. QLibrary slightly changed in Qt 5. You did not mention the operating system either, the installed opencl version, just in case, etc.

Comment: @LaszloPapp added the information. What is backtrace and how do I get it? Which library version are you talking about?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg even if I use new to allocate the array I am still getting segmentation fault... Does this mean the function was not resolved properly?

Comment: @Cool_Coder: just run the code through gdb with debug infomation available, and then type backtrace. Also, you do not mark that in the snippet where it actually crashes. Furthermore, does it crash the first time this method is being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `clGetPlatformIDs` is the number of elements the driver is allowed to write to the array pointed to by the second element.

If the first call, you are passing INT_MAX and NULL for these. I'd expect a crash here because you are telling the driver to go ahead and write through your NULL pointer.

You should pass 0 for the first parameter since all you are interested in is the returned third parameter value.

In the second call you at least pass valid memory for the second parameter, but you again pass INT_MAX. Here you should pass `nplatforms` since that is how much memory you allocated. For the third parameter, pass NULL since you don't need the return value (again).

Comment: Thank You for answering. Based on your suggestions I have made the changes and have updated the code above. But still I am getting segmentation fault. What more could be wrong?

Comment: Thanks for also updating your code in the original questions. I haven't used the QLibrary "lib->resolve" technique but I'm guess it isn't working for some reason. Where is `MyPlatorms` declared (also, check spelling)?

Comment: MyPlatforms is the function pointer to clGetPlatformIDs. It does not need a declaration. Also I finding a lot fishy business over here. When first call to pobj completes I am getting nplatoforms as 1. After the second call to pinfoobj nplatforms is becoming 2768. Also size is also changing its value at the memory allocation statement of ver, which is absolutely non sense. So does this mean that Qt has not linked properly?

Comment: considering the disadvantages of delay loading I think I will add my OpenCL code in a sepparate dll which will be statically linked to OpenCL.lib from the SDK. In my executable I will check if OpenCL.dll exists. If yes then I will load my dll and use OpenCL functionality. This seems to the only option as of now. What do you do in your applications?

Comment: We use /DELAYLOAD on OpenCL.dll. Previously we dynamically loaded OpenCL.dll and had a GetProcAddress wrapper around each API, but that was messy.

Comment: I was scared of using DELAYLOAD after reading the disadvantages over here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2007/08/01/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-delay-load-loadlibrary.aspx. Do you feel what I am doing now is also an acceptable solution?

Comment: #6 can be mitigated by registering a callback that handles missing DLL, or you can check for OpenCL.dll using LoadLibrary first.